# No cipher suites in common when reading https ajax request

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to create an `SSLServerSocket` but I'm getting this exception `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common` when I try to read headers/body from an https ajax request. I can solve this problem using these lines of code:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "PKCS12");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "C:/cert/ssl.pfx");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "password");
```

But this code will run on customers machine, so that I can not send `.pfx` files to every customer (I've read that it contains the private key). So, is there any way I can set keyStore with `.cer` file (since it does not contain the private key), or any other solution to this problem?

Comment: If you're setting up a *server* socket (assuming the roles aren't reversed), then you'll need a certificate with its private key. It's quite unusual to ship a server to your customer (although it can happen). Is it going to be on localhost or something?

Comment: The customer should create his own private key and certificate. Your code should just rely on the customer putting them into a specified location.

Comment: Yes, it will be on localhost @Bruno. Is there anything I can do via code (like creating the private key and certificate programatically) to avoid customers from having this kind of work?